# how to set the action for accessoryView except the didselectrow at index path in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Actually i am create action for custom accessory view uibutton in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event{
      [self tableView: self.grouptableview accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

its working fine when i didn't use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

**Problem is:** some times the click event in accessory view not recognize instead of it triggers the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function. 
How to i specify the user interaction for accessory view and differentiate from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in `tableview` ?

please help me to solve this. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like design Problem.

```
(0, 0, 25, 25)
```

get a new image from your designer with more transparent area towards top, down, left and right.
It will solve your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: is it depends on the image size?  its already the same size what i give in addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the height and width of your `uibutton` which you are specifying in your program. function `CGRectMake` defines the position and the area your button covers which is small and enables a user to perform its functions like `touchupinside` `touchupoutside` etc.

Sometimes user touch over a button but at that time `cell` gets focus and executes accordingly because of `uibutton` cover area over it.